# How to find inverse Fourier transform of rational expression involving trig polynomials

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Given a rational expression (already in simplest form) with unique coefficients $a,b,c,d,e,f$

$$g(\omega)=\frac{a\cos(\omega)^2-b\cos(\omega)+c}{d\cos(\omega)^2-e\cos(\omega)+f}$$

How would I go about finding the inverse Fourier transform of $g$?

I'm not even sure where to start.

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by the "x arrow" thing. Also, "f" is a coefficient. Maybe I should change "x" into "$\omega$" to emphasis that the expression is in spectral space

Comment: Yeah...that works